# Multiple regression with 2 IVs and a moderator in SPSS

Tags: multiple-regression

I am running a multiple regression with 2 continuous independent variables and one continuous dependent variable and a categorical moderator. I am doing this in SPSS. I am not sure how to proceed. Please help!! My question is how do (1st continuous variable) and (2nd continuous variable) differentially predict (Continuous Dv) for (categorical variable split into it's 2 categories.

Comment: Do you mean you have a regression model and you'd like to perform this model to two different sub-groups separately, like males only and females only?

Comment: So my question is do anxiety and avoidance differentially predict mainstream culture identification for westerners and non westerners.I am doing this in SPSS and I don't have much experience with SPSS. Would I just run the regression model twice for each IV and do a simple slope separately? DO I have to do an interaction (because it says differentially predict?)

Comment: From your use of word "moderator" I'd suppose there should be interaction term(s).

Answer (score 3):

Likely what you want to do is to test whether the 'interaction term' is significant. This will test whether the slopes are significantly different from each other in the two groups.

In SPSS go to Analyze-->General Linear Model-->Univariate.

Put your DV in the DV slot. Put your continuous variables in the 'Covariates' box and put your categorical variable in the 'fixed factor' box. Click on the 'Model' tab and choose 'Custom'. Then move all of your IV over from the left to the right box. Then choose the 'interaction' option and move the continuous IV, together with the categorical IV over to the right hand box.

When you run your model the output will include the interaction term.

Here is a nice walkthrough that looks at various ways of checking if the relation between two continuous variables is the same or different for two different groups (it's all brought together on the last page so you might want to skim through that first):

http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/statpage/rhtest_eg2a.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and thank you for the link as well

Comment: Also, remember to click the Option button and check the "parameter estimates" box. Otherwise there will be no regression coefficients reported. It'd also be helpful if you specify General Linear Model (which is what is referring in  your answer) and Generalized Linear Model, both are listed under Analysis drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: I was writing from memory (need to re-install SPSS)...Those are both helpful comments.