# R: Test significance of difference in slopes of same correlations in different groups

Tags: r, regression

Say I have two groups of observations `A` and `B`. Each group contains the SAME two set of observations `a_1,a_2` and `b_1,b_2`. For group `A`, I estimate how well `a_1` and `a_2` are correlated by computing Spearman's Correlation Coefficient between `a_1` and `a_2` and likewise for group `B`. How do I assess the magnitude of the difference?

E.g. think of it this way: Group `A` is women and group `B` is men. `a_1` is weight and so is `b_1`. Likewise `a_2` and `b_2` are heights. How do I asses sif there is a significant difference in how weight and height are connected in men and women?

I guess it comes down to assuming linearity and then constructing and comparing two linear models, one for men and one for women?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather construct *one* linear model, containing the sex and the height as explanatory variables *plus* their interaction. (The response being the weight.) Then, the significance of the interaction term tells you whether there is a ''difference in how weight and height are connected in men and women''. (Given, of course, the model is diagnostically correct.)

In R:

```
 summary( lm( Weight ~ Height * Sex, data = YourData ) )
```

and then look for the `Height:Sex` term.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have been suggested to take a closer look at this site for comparing the two Spearman's Correlation Coefficients: http://www.quantpsy.org/corrtest/corrtest.htm
I'm not sure exactly how to 'attack' this question though...?

Comment: @LeonDK : The regression approach I suggested generalizes the Pearson (linear) correlation coefficient. That link pertains to Spearman's correlation coefficient. You should decide whether it is acceptable to use linear correlation in your particular problem - if so, then I believe my suggestion should work.

Comment: Note that Spearman correlation could be the same for quite different relationships, and different for the same underlying relationship.

Comment: You can also see the related answer posted here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141325/multiple-regression-with-2-ivs-and-a-moderator-in-spss/141343#141343

Comment: @tamas-ferenci : How do I "...decide whether it is acceptable to use linear correlation in your particular problem"? I should probably add, that I will be comparing in the neighbourhood of 1,000,000 correlations in group `A` vs. group `B`...

Comment: @LeonDK : I'd definitely start with plotting a scattergram between the variables, separated (different panels or different colors) according to the grouping factor. (That is very beneficial in general, too!) However, if you have such huge number of observations, you'll almost surely face the following two problems. (1) Direct scatter plot might be useless (points will simply cover the whole range). How to deal with it is a separate question, estimating their joint density with KDE is my first idea. (2) The interaction term will be sure significant - the effect size will be interesting instead.

Comment: @tamas-ferenci : I am trying to implement your answer like so: `mylm = lm(formula = response ~ explanatory * interaction, data = myData)`, where the `interaction` is numeric with values `0` and `1`. I have around 50 real valued response variables and around 20,000 real valued explanatory values. I then retrieve the p-value like so: `summary(mylm)$coefficients["explanatory:interaction","Pr(>|t|)"`. Which I believe is what you suggested? However I am now facing the following error message: `Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities` and this coefficient is the one for `interaction`!

Comment: @LeonDK : ??? How could you have more explanatory variable than response??

Comment: @TamasFerenci : For each of the 50 real valued `response` variables I am trying to estimate if 1) there is a connection to each of the 20,000 `explanatory` variables and 2) if there is a difference in that connection based on the `interaction` variable. Each correlation of `response ~ explanatory * interaction` is based on around `n=100` data points. I hope this clarifies?

Comment: @LeonDK : I understood your question as if you have more observations for explanatory variables than for response. OK, now its clear. Is "response" one of the response variables and "explanatory" one of the explanatory variables? If so, this should work; I can't say more specific without a reproducible example. Consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The question here should be turned around. Consider

1. I am interested in (e.g.) the relationship between height and weight for men and women.
2. A linear model is one way to approach this.
3. Spearman correlation is a descriptive method that could be used.

Point 1 really is primary here statistically just as it should be scientifically.

Then in point 2 linearity (whether linearity in variables or linearity in parameters) is something to be checked, rather than assumed, but there are easy graphs to help as well as formal tests.

On point 3, Spearman correlation has its uses, but they do not loom large here. You will find formal ways of comparing correlations but they won't really illuminate point 1.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not studying height and weight in men and women, that was purely for illustrative purposes :-)

Comment: OK; answer edited accordingly.

Comment: I am interested in identifying if the height-weight relationship is DIFFERENT between men and women and if so HOW different. I.e. I 'need' a p-value quantifying how DIFFERENT the Men:height-weight relationship is compared to women:heigh-weight - Make sense?

Comment: @Tamas Ferenci has addressed this. You need to translate "different relationship" into a hypothesis about parameter values, just as answering a question in ordinary conversation of whether men and women are similar or different demands a precise criterion (or is meaningless otherwise). Even with simple linear relationships, intercepts may differ, slopes may differ, etc.