# Two models of different data (sub)sets significantly different?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, fitting

I need to see if different fits of different data sets are significantly different, preferrably in R.

I have sample series A, B and C. These are different in length and all contain variables *n, m, o* which in turn depend on variables *x, y, z*...

Fitting these different series to assess how they behave as we change *x, y, z* is easy enough, but how can I check if a fit assessing series A variable *n* is significantly different from one concerning series B or C, variable *n*?

Or to put it differently:

```
mydata=read.csv("Data.csv")
fitA=lm(Formula=n ~ x + y + z,subset=Group=="A",data=mydata)
fitB=lm(Formula=n ~ x + y + z,subset=Group=="B",data=mydata)
fitC=lm(Formula=n ~ x + y + z,subset=Group=="C",data=mydata)
sometest(fitA,fitB,fitC)
```

What can I use where I squeezed in sometest? Not necessarily using lm as the fitting method, but for the current data set it appears suitable, so we can assume it is for this question.

Comment: You refer to these as "series", are they time series data or cross-sectional? Is there any reason you can't fit a model that includes all 3?

Comment: Cross sectional. I don't think fitting all three series into one function will help as I need to see if there are differences between the series. I need to see how samples in series A behave in response to changed x, y, z as compared to how samples in series B or C behaves in response to the same changes. The x, y, z variables are *likely* independent. My naïve assumption (I am no statistician. At all.) was to fit them using MLR or somesuch and compare the fits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in comparing $R^2$ for different groups you can extract the $R^2$ using:

```
R_Sq_A <- summary(fitA)$r.squared
    R_Sq_B <- summary(fitB)$r.squared
```

These can then be compared using:

```
library(psych)
paired.r(sqrt(R_Sq_A), sqrt(R_Sq_B), NULL, 
         dim(mydata[which(Group=="A"),][1], dim(mydata[which(Group=="B"),][1])
```

You can replace the `dim(mydata[which(Group=="A"),][1]` with the size of Group A since you know what that is.

Comment: The OP's question doesn't seem to be about $R^2$, but if the coefficients associated with the variables change.

Comment: It seems to be about how the collective change of 'x, y, and z' affects various outcome variables. That can be interpreted at R^2...maybe I'm misreading though. If it's about the different effect of, say, x on Outcome1 for the three different groups, the entire sample should be used with a categorical variable indicating group membership say G - this varaible should be included in the model with an interaction term G*x...

Comment: This shows how to test of 'different slopes' between groups (in SPSS, but it's easily extended to R): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141325/multiple-regression-with-2-ivs-and-a-moderator-in-spss/141343#141343

Comment: R squared is not a definitive solution to my question, is it? I confess, it has been years since my last statistics course, so I freely admit to being fairly ignorant on this, but I recall that R2 has some pitfalls. I would expect a method for comparing different fits of the three situations would be more robust.

Comment: It's not a definitive solution, no - just a quick and common one and one where 'significance' can be easily tested for - which was in your question; this is what my answer provides. Since you're fitting three different models, it looks like you're interested in how well x,y,z explain Outcome1 in Group 1 vs Group 2, say. R^2 will give you this. The 'pitfalls' of R^2 that you're remembering might have to do with comparing nested models: models with more independent variables will have a higher R^2...so adjusted R^2 is used, for instance. But that's not what the question said was of interest...

Comment: Here's a useful guide (not for comparing fits across different datasets, but as a reminder of what R^2, etc is looking at): http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/EPIB-621/fit.pdf   and the first two pages of this document http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/statpage/rhtest_eg2a.pdf outlines what's in my answer (their FZT program just translates the R^2s into z-scores via a Fisher transformation, I believe, and then tests whether they're sig. different - should be equivalent to what I provided). The next bunch of pages outline what else you might be interested in if that's not it...